# jQuery background animation initial opacity wrong in IE only

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am animating the background of a div in order to produce the gold button effect you see on http://farshadzandi.ca

The code is as follows:

```
$(function(){
  $(".navigation").hover(function(){
    $(this).children('.background').stop(true,true).animate({opacity: 1},250);
  }, function(){
    $(this).children('.background').stop(true,true).animate({opacity: 0},250);
  });
});

$(function(){
  $(".lower-navigation").hover(function(){
    $(this).children('.lower-background').stop(true,true).animate({opacity: 1},250);
  }, function(){
    $(this).children('.lower-background').stop(true,true).animate({opacity: 0},250);
  });
});
```

Can anyone tell me why although this is working jsut fine in Firefox/Chrome, it shows the background image in IE when the page loads?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IE you have to use the following CSS syntax.

```
/* IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

/* IE 5-7 */
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
```

Comment: Jeez, I should have know that.  Thank you!!